# Php api for reading any text from image wahtever we uplaod

Tags: php, ocr

I need help in to read text from image whatever we upload.Is there any library for this. I am using Tesseract PHP OCR.

But not getting idea to use it . I am attaching my file here.

Tesseract file is from here: https://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php/tree/master/src
and my php i have written attached image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hkIz.png)

Comment: Have you install tesseract ocr?

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example (MVCE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to improve your question and chances to get an answer.

Comment: Did you install tesseract on your web host? are you getting any php errors?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little script I use to do ocr for pdfs on ubuntu 16.04

```
$inputPDF = 'path/to /your/file';
$fileToOCR = "ocr.tiff";
exec("convert -density 300 $inputPDF -depth 8 -strip -background white -alpha off $fileToOCR");
$outputOCR = "ocr";
exec("tesseract $fileToOCR -l deu+eng $outputOCR hocr");
```

note that you need tesseract-ocr and imagemagick installed `sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr imagemagick`

also you need the language packs you want to use `sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr-[lang]`

`exec("convert ...");` prepares the file for better results

`exec("tesseract ... ");` does the actual ocr where deu+eng is the language from the text and  hocr is the output format (xml with additional infos where the text was found)

hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

Hello you can use this libary for that

https://www.phpclasses.org/package/3312-PHP-Hide-encrypted-data-in-images-using-steganography.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference/download. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the original question as the OP wants to extract visible text from an image not text hidden in an image.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this API (it's free):

```
<?php
$url = 'http://server.com/image.png';
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.rest7.com/v1/ocr.php?url=' . $url . '&format=txt'));

if (@$data->success !== 1)
{
    die('Failed');
}
$txt = file_get_contents($data->file);
file_put_contents('text.txt', $txt);
```

You should just replace `$url` with URL to your image file and the output will be save as `text.txt`.